# 3 Table SQL JOIN with CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, symfony

I need the `h.target_date` to replace the `d.deadline` where `h.flux_id` is equal to the parameter `:docId` (a primary key of a table).

I have worked on the below query which doesn't do the job.

```
   $sqlsteptarget = "SELECT 
                            h.target_date,
                            h.flux_id,
                            d.deadline,
                          CASE
                            WHEN h.target_date is null THEN h.target_date = d.deadline
                          END AS date_cible
                          FROM
                            public.flux_historique AS h 
                          LEFT JOIN public.flux as f 
                            INNER JOIN public.document as d
                            ON d.id = :docId
                          ON h.flux_id = f.id 
                          WHERE
                             f.id_system_droit_id = d.id_system_droit_id
                          ";
        $stmtfh = $conn->prepare($sqlsteptarget);
        $stmtfh->execute(['docId' => $docId]);
        $data3 = $stmtfh->fetchAll();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try with `coalesce(h.target_date, d.deadline) AS date_cible` So when h.target_date is null, the d.deadline replace it.

I'm sorry but you mean : h.target_date have to replace d.deadline but you have write the opposite in your query... Or i didn't get something

Comment: h.target_date must replace d.deadline if it exists. I apologize for being a beginner in sql

Comment: It's ok you don't have to apologize, we've all start somewhere.
Can you try coalesce and tell us what you got ?

Comment: you tagged your post as symfony, your database isn't mapped by Doctrine ?

Comment: Yes Pierrick, it is, however native SQL queries are faster and this is key because the project is quite big in terms of data consumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
SELECT 
    h.target_date,
    h.flux_id,
    COALESCE(h.target_date,d.deadline) AS date_cible
  FROM
    public.flux_historique AS h 
  LEFT JOIN public.flux as f 
    INNER JOIN public.document as d
    ON d.id = :docId
  ON h.flux_id = f.id 
  WHERE
     f.id_system_droit_id = d.id_system_droit_id
```

Of course, you can do that only if at least one of the both (target_date or deadline) is not null in all case

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code, when you are using ***CASE*** you can use operator (=) after ***WHEN*** only. You can't use it after the ***THEN***.

```
   $sqlsteptarget = "SELECT 
                            h.target_date,
                            h.flux_id,
                            d.deadline,
                          CASE
                            WHEN h.target_date is null THEN  d.deadline
                          END AS date_cible
                          FROM
                            public.flux_historique AS h 
                          LEFT JOIN public.flux as f 
                            INNER JOIN public.document as d
                            ON d.id = :docId
                          ON h.flux_id = f.id 
                          WHERE
                             f.id_system_droit_id = d.id_system_droit_id
                          ";
        $stmtfh = $conn->prepare($sqlsteptarget);
        $stmtfh->execute(['docId' => $docId]);
        $data3 = $stmtfh->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't achieve what I need as the column "date_cible" doesn't contain either the h.target_date if it exists, and if not, the d.deadline. Thanks for letting me know about the equal oeprator used cases

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $sqlsteptarget = "SELECT   h.target_date, h.flux_id, d.deadline,
if(h.target_date is null,d.deadline,h.target_date)  AS date_cible
  FROM
  public.flux_historique AS h 
  LEFT JOIN public.flux as f 
  INNER JOIN public.document as d ON f.id_system_droit_id = 
   d.id_system_droit_id
  AND h.flux_id = f.id 
  WHERE d.id = :docId;                              ";
            $stmtfh = $conn->prepare($sqlsteptarget);
            $stmtfh->execute(['docId' => $docId]);
            $data3 = $stmtfh->fetchAll();
```